# C# ComboBox and TextBox dynamic value - How can I access a TextBox value from another function or event?

Tags: c#, object, dynamic

l write some code under page. l created 2 object. (staff combobox and tcnu textbox). When l created staff Combobox l can access from staff_SelectedValueChanged() but l want to that: When l change value of staff_SelectedValueChange write new value to tckNu(textbox). How can l access if l creat a dynamic value from other funcion or event? l hope l can explain my problem. Sorry for my poor english. Thanks everybody..

```
void personalCall()
        {            
            try
            {
                SQLiteConnection conn= new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=vt/aksehirmeb.db");
                conn.Open();

                SQLiteCommand kmt = new SQLiteCommand("Select * from Personel", conn);
                kmt.ExecuteNonQuery();

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SQLiteDataAdapter adp = new SQLiteDataAdapter(kmt);
                adp.Fill(dt);
                
                for (int increase = 0; increase < Convert.ToInt32(personelNumber.Text); increase++)
                {
                    //Creat Combobox
                    ComboBox staff = new ComboBox();
                    staff.Name= "staff" + increase;
                    staff.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
                    //Creat Textbox  
                    TextBox tckNu = new TextBox();
                    tckNu.Name = "tcknu" + increase;                    

                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) // Fill combobox with data 
                    {
                     staff.Items.Add(dr["staffName"].ToString() + "-" + dr["staffSurname"].ToString());                        
                    }

                    //Position Combobox
                    staff.Left = startPosition.Left + 50;
                    staff.Top = startPosition.Top + increase * 25;
                    staff.SelectedValueChanged += staff_SelectedValueChanged;

                    //Position Textbox
                    tckNu.Left= startPosition.Left + 175;
                    tckNu.Top= startPosition.Top + increase * 25;
                    tckNu.ReadOnly = true;

                    panel1.Controls.Add(staff); //                                                      
                    panel1.Controls.Add(tckNu); //
                }
                conn.Close(); 
            }            
        }



 private void staff_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //l can access combobox value 
            MessageBox.Show("ComboBoxsenderText= " + ((ComboBox)sender).Text);
            //l want write this value textbox(tckNu.text). But l dont know how can l access tckNu.text 
            
        }
```

i tried some things but realy l didnt find fix problem.